# secure Web Services using https and SAML

Tags: web-services

i have question about how i apply https and SAML to secure web services
i already implement web services using ASP.NET web services application project with C#
but i have to enhance this web services

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Configuration;

  namespace simpleWeb_services
  {
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
     // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, 
uncomment    the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
 public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {

    [WebMethod]
    public string Getinfo(int id)
    {
        string name = "";

        SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection();

        connection1.ConnectionString = 
(username,password)VALUES(' "+ username +" ',"+ password +")", connection);
        connection1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username from [userTable] where  
userid=" + id + "", connection1);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            name = reader[0].ToString();
        }

        return name;
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the legacy ASMX web service technology. That's a mistake.

ASMX should not be used for new development. You should use WCF instead. In particular, WCF supports what you're looking for and much more.

---

To be clear: this answer isn't about "use the new stuff because it's *new*". It's about "the new stuff does what you want, and the old stuff will never do anything more than it does now".